# Is there any SE site where questions regarding reporting bugs can be asked?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, site-recommendation, off-topic, bug-reports

A question regarding where to post bugs was flagged as off topic at SO.
[Is it possible to log a bug report for JDK 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22440353/is-it-possible-to-log-a-bug-report-for-jdk-5)

Where should this question have been asked?

Should a new site be created under Area 51 for this?

Comment: You posted two different questions regarding this on SO.  You were told that it's off-topic, and that you should be contacting Oracle.  If you are not an enterprise customer, then you have little luck since JDK 5 is EOL looooooong time back.

Comment: @devnull The second question was created after the first was flagged as off-topic and subsequently updated to comply further with SO's QA format. My understanding is still that the second question while related, is not off topic. Just to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a Stack Exchange site is the proper venue to report software bugs. The developers should provide channels for that, be it corporate forums, web forms, GitHub repositories and similar.

I'm not sure if it's the correct page (it was a fast googling), but if [these are the requirements to report a bug](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/bugreports.html) on JDK 7, holy crap!

I think discovering a bug, trying to overcome it, can be fair game at SO.
But a site to report *bugs*... in general... probably won't hold water. Of course, proposing it at Area 51 is free for all. Just do it ;)

Comment: I never did intend to use SO for reporting the bugs. Just wanted to know if there were any popular medium for doing them (especially for non enterprise users) and asked that question on SO. Thanks for your inputs though.

Comment: Created a new proposal at area 51 - http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66412/open-and-newly-discovered-bugs-in-eold-software